# Marshalling C++ win32 types in struct to be used in function in C#

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, marshalling

I have written a working C++ DLL. I want to use it in .NET C# application, however i have difficulties marshalling the types as i am not so familiar with C# and still learning. DLL works fine when used in C++ written program.

Here's the DLL *header*:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
    #define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct clientInfo
{
    HANDLE processHandle = NULL;
    uintptr_t baseAddress = NULL;
};

extern "C" MYDLL_API bool hook(const wchar_t* window_name, const wchar_t* module_name, clientInfo &info);
```

Basically the function opens a handle with all access to the given window, and also finds module base address for the given module name and puts them in clientInfo structure that was passed as reference in function arguments. Returns true upon success or false if it doesn't work.

The implementation of this isn't necessary for my question, at least i think.
Now in .NET Windows Forms C# application i have set a nice looking form that informs me if on button click the function succeeded or failed. With my C# code, it compiles but it doesn't quite work. **How do i marshal the structure and my function correctly in C#?**

*My not working C# code:*

```cs
// Structure marshalling
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 public struct clientInfo
 {
     public IntPtr processHandle;

     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
     public uint gameBaseAddress;
 };

// Function marshalling
[DllImport("C:\\Users\\Cira\\source\\repos\\myDll\\Debug\\myDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern bool hook(string window_name, string module_name, out clientInfo info);
```

Comment: Every thing looks good except the strings : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings

Comment: uint for the address should be UIntPtr. And the charset should be Unicode.

Comment: Can only add that the path should be relative or absent... You can't compile inside a program an absolute path like the one you wrote. Not because the compiler will give an error, but because you'll want to execute on a computer where the Cira user isn't present :-)

Comment: By far the easiest and most robust way to interop between native code and .NET is C++/CLI. It allows you to produce mixed-mode assemblies that are immediately consumable by .NET. You can decide whether you wish to put your native code into that assembly, or link that assembly against your native DLL's import library. See [Native and .NET Interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/native-and-dotnet-interoperability) for details.